# Armstrong numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm having problems with this practice question.

> Write a Ruby script to display the number of Armstrong numbers in an array of numbers.
>
> An Armstrong number is a number in which the sum of [the] cubes of the digits of the number is [the] same as the number. For instance, 153, 370 and 371 are Armstrong numbers. Example:
>
> ```
> 153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 1 + 125 + 27 = 153
> ```
>
> Sample input
>
> ```
> numbers = [123, 124, 153, 370, 234, 23, 45]
> ```
>
> Then the output will be
>
> ```
> There are 2 Armstrong numbers in the list.
> ```

My code is the following:

```
def get
  number = [123, 124, 153, 370, 234, 23, 45]
  s = number.count{}
  new_num = number
  sum = 0

  while new_num > 0
    sum = sum + (new_num % 10) * (new_num % 10) * (new_num % 10)
    new_num = new_num / 10
    number.count(new_num)
  end

  if sum == number
    puts "There are #{s} Armstrong"
  end
end
```

It gives no output, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: What's an Armstrong number?

Comment: Unfortunately SO is not a codewriting service.  If you can show us what you've come up with so far, and any specific problems, we can try and help.

Comment: An Armstrong number is a number in which the sum of cubes of the digits of the number is same as the number. For instance, 153, 370 and 371 are Armstrong numbers.
Example: 153=1**3
+5**3
+3**3
=1+125+27=153

Comment: def get
  number=[123,124,153,370,234,23,45]
 s= number.count{}
new_num=number
sum=0
while(new_num>0)
sum=sum+(new_num%10)*(new_num%10)*(new_num%10)
new_num=new_num/10
number.count(new_num)
 end
if sum==number
puts "There are #{s} Armstrong"
end
end                                                                                                                             My codes gives no output and i don't know why

Comment: I've added the code you posted to your question, try to avoid posting code in comments, there's no formatting down here and that makes things hard to read and comments aren't guaranteed to stick around, which causes the question to lose context.

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested you can utilise `digits`. Used with `reduce` you can write something like this:

```
number.select { |n| n.digits.reduce(0) { |m, n| m + n**3 } == n }
 #=> [153, 370]
```

Comment: If the purpose is to only count such numbers, then you can replace `select` with `count`.

Comment: @sawa yes you are correct. An oversight by myself. I will leave the OP to modify my code with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If the method must be used frequently, one can save time by defining a constant holding a set (rather than an array, for faster lookup) of the [first so-many Armstrong numbers](http://oeis.org/A005188). For example,

```
require 'set'

FIRST_ARMSTRONG_NUMBERS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407, 1634,
   8208, 9474, 54748, 92727, 93084, 548834, 1741725, 4210818, 9800817, 9926315,
   24678050, 24678051, 88593477, 146511208, 472335975, 534494836, 912985153,
   4679307774, 32164049650, 32164049651].to_set
     #=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407, 1634, 8208,
     #           9474, 54748, 92727, 93084, 548834, 1741725, 4210818,
     #           9800817, 9926315, 24678050, 24678051, 88593477, 146511208,
     #           472335975, 534494836, 912985153, 4679307774, 32164049650,
     #           32164049651}>
MAX_FIRST_ARMSTRONG_NUMBERS = FIRST_ARMSTRONG_NUMBERS.max
  #=> 32164049651

def count_armstrong_numbers(arr)
  arr.count do |n|
    if n <= MAX_FIRST_ARMSTRONG_NUMBERS
      FIRST_ARMSTRONG_NUMBERS.include?(n)
    else
      n.digits.sum { |d| d**3 } == n
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a good idea and a pretty nifty sum block. Just out of interest how did you generate `FIRST_ARMSTRONG_NUMBERS`? Also I don't think you need the `to_a` as `FIRST_ARMSTRONG_NUMBERS.max #=> 32164049651`

Comment: @Sagar, Google provided the list of Armstrong numbers. Thanks for noting that I didn't need `.to_a`. I found there is no method `Set#max` but forgot `Set` includes `Enumerable`, which of course has `max`.  It did seem like there should be a `max` method for `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using a recent ruby version

```
  def armstrong?(number)
    number.digits.sum { |x| x**number.digits.size } == number 
  end
```